# Problem authenticating w/SOAP and Access Token

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, c#

When attempting to use the Marketing Cloud (building an app for it), we are getting an error message when using our obtained Access Token:

The security token could not be authenticated or authorized ---> A critical error has occurred and has caused an authentication failure. The error has been logged. Please try again and if the issue persists please contact customer support. ---> SOAP Authorization failed for Oauth token: [redacted]. Reason: ParseError.

As far as I can tell, we are getting correct tokens and end-points from the system, when I run it in debug mode, I can see the endpoints being called and the tokens being provided, and when these methods are called I get values successfully. 
[image]

It's only when I try to do something (ie retrieve lists) do I get the error message above.

This was primarily via following the repo that had been pointed out to us by a SF employee (all examples in documenation show username/password methods, but not how to use an Access Token with SOAP):
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/blob/Dot9/FuelSDK-CSharp/ET_Client.cs#L154

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using cURL?

```
## Get Access Token
curl -X "POST" "https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d $'{
  "clientSecret": "YOUR_SECRET",
  "clientId": "YOUR_ID"
}'
```

and then making your other call using the resulting `authToken`?

For Example (replace with the call you're trying to make):

```
## Get CloudPages
curl "https://consumer.exacttargetapis.com/device/v1/YOUR_APP_ID/message/?deviceid=YOUR_DEVICE_ID&messagetype=1&contenttype=2" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```